What parallels exist between the Pepé Le Pew cartoon "For Scent-imental Reasons" and "Joker: Folie à Deux"?
In Joker: Folie à Deux (2024), near the film's conclusion, there's a scene where Arthur Fleck and other Arkham Asylum inmates watch the 1949 Looney Tunes short film For Scent-imental Reasons, featuring Pepé Le Pew and Penelope Pussycat.

According to the Wikipedia article for For Scent-imental Reasons, "the short was extensively used as a plot point in Joker: Folie à Deux, to represent the relationship between [Arthur] Fleck and [Lee] Quinzel." However, there isn’t a proper source to back this up.
The decision to show For Scent-imental Reasons to Arthur Fleck and the other Arkham inmates seems to have significance. I'd like to understand the parallels the filmmakers may have intended between the cartoon and Joker: Folie à Deux. Are there character similarities? Does Arthur correspond to Pepé Le Pew and Lee to Penelope Pussycat, or is it the other way around? In what ways? What specific plot points from the cartoon reflect the film's narrative, or vice versa?

You can watch For Scent-imental Reasons on YouTube; multiple versions have been included in case any of them are restricted based on your location:







This seems a bit opinion-based as written. I assume you mean "what did the makers intend to be the parallels"

@Valorum Yes. I reworded my post accordingly.

Pepé’s presence parallels Arthur’s inevitable downfall. Akin to Arthur’s narcissistic tendencies, Pepé is in love with himself, blissfully unaware of how others feel about him. Pepé and Arthur are hopeless romantics, willing to put a gun to their heads for love. There's more at the link. Not posting it as an answer because I have not seen JFAD.
